# Is there a way to find which iptables rule was responsible for dropping a packet?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have a system that came with a firewall already in place. The firewall consists of over 1000 iptables rules. One of these rule is dropping packets I don't want dropped. (I know this because I did `iptables-save` followed by `iptables -F` and the application started working.) There are way too many rules to sort through manually. Can I do something to show me which rule is dropping the packets?

Comment: https://fedorahosted.org/dropwatch/ might also be helpful in the future.

Comment: To see the counters update in real time use<br/>
<code>
watch iptables -L -v -n
</code>

Comment: You can also use the `iptables -nvL -t filter` command to display only the rules in the filter table, which is where most packet-filtering rules are located.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could add a TRACE rule early in the chain to log every rule that the packet traverses.

I would consider using `iptables -L -v -n | less` to let you search the rules. I would look port; address; and interface rules that apply.  Given that you have so many rules you are likely running a mostly closed firewall, and are missing a permit rule for the traffic.

How is the firewall built?  It may be easier to look at the builder rules than the built rules.

Comment: I figured out after asking this question that the rules are from APF, and I was able to fix that. I love the TRACE target, though. That would have been very effective.

Comment: An example of using TRACE target is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/122157/debugger-for-iptables/126079#126079.

Answer (score 23):

Since `iptables -L -v -n` has counters you could do the following.

```
iptables -L -v -n > Sample1
#Cause the packet that you suspect is being dropped by iptables
iptables -L -v -n > Sample2
diff Sample1 Sample2
```

This way you will see only the rules that incremented.

Answer (score 15):

Run `iptables -L -v -n` to see the packet and byte counters for every table and for every rule.

Comment: This is good, I'm hoping for something better since there are 1000 rules and 1000s of dropped packets.

Comment: Use `sort` to sort rules by packet counter.

Answer (score 11):

In my company we use `watch -n 2 -d iptables -nvL`, it shows changes between requests

Answer (score 8):

```
watch -n1 -d "iptables -tfilter -vnxL | grep -vE 'pkts|Chain' | sort -nk1hr | column -t"
```

Keep in mind, this will only show stuff for the table **filter**.

If you want all tables, try this:

```
watch -n1 -d "(iptables -tfilter -vnxL;iptables -tnat -vnxL;iptables -tmangle -vnxL;iptables -traw -vnxL;iptables -tsecurity -vnxL) | grep -vE 'pkts|Chain' | sort -nk1,1hr | column -t"
```

Comment: The most complete solution IMHO.
`| tac` can be dropped in favour of add `-r` to the `sort` command.

Comment: @ZaarHai thanks for the flowers, edited considering your input and also fixed the sorting which lacked `-h`.